# Tensorflow dlopen fails with no other warnings

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a newly installed linux mint 21.1 and I'm trying to use tensorflow but I get the following error:

```
$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf;tf.config.list_physical_devices()"
2023-04-16 00:25:24.827994: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:110] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2023-04-16 00:25:25.073486: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI AVX512_BF16 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-04-16 00:25:26.881014: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-04-16 00:25:26.881251: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1956] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

Usually there is a warning about which library it was not able to load but here is nothing.

GPU is ASUS rog strix rtx 3090

python version is `3.10.6`
tensorflow version is `2.12.0`
cuda version is `11.8.0-1`
cudnn is `8.6.0.163-1+cuda11.8`
tensorrt is `8.6.0.12-1+cuda11.8`

NVIDIA driver is currently `515.105.01` but I have tried `520` and `525`, the error remained the same.

`nvidia-smi` shows no sign of error.
PyTorch can use the GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try again setting up the configuration to install the TensorFlow with GPU support by re-verifying all the steps mentioned in the TensorFlow official [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

Please make sure all the Hardware/Software requirements are fulfilled and set the path after downloading the required softwares(Nvidia driver, CUDA, cuDNN) as shown in the link.

Let us know if the issue still persists.